# Why do I get "Undefined index: recaptcha_response_field"?

Tags: php, recaptcha

This is my form code:

```
echo '
              <div class="ctext" id="form">
                    <table><form method="post" action="prashanja.php">
                    <tr><td>Name:</td><td><input type="text" name="name"/></td></tr>
                   <tr><td>Question:</td><td><textarea cols="55" rows="4" name="prashanje">    </textarea></td></tr>
                   <tr><td></td><td >' . recaptcha_get_html($publickey) . '<button name="btn" value="submit">Enter</button></td></tr>
                   </form></table>
                 </div>';
```

And this is the validation code:

```
if (isset($_POST['btn'])) {
    $name = mysql_real_escape_string(strip_tags($_POST['name']));
    $prashanje = mysql_real_escape_string(strip_tags($_POST['prashanje']));
    $date = time();

    # the response from reCAPTCHA
    $resp = null;
    # the error code from reCAPTCHA, if any
    $error = null;

    # was there a reCAPTCHA response?
    if ($_POST["recaptcha_response_field"]) {
        $resp = recaptcha_check_answer($privatekey, $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"], $_POST["recaptcha_challenge_field"], $_POST["recaptcha_response_field"]);

        if ($resp->is_valid) {
            $query = "INSERT INTO prashanja VALUES(NULL,'$name','$prashanje','','$date')";
            if (!mysql_query($query))
                echo 's... happens';
            else
                echo 'cool';
        } else {
            # set the error code so that we can display it
            $error = $resp->error;
        }
    }
}
```

These segments are on the same page. The first segment generates the form and the second segment checks if the correct button is pressed, initializes the variables and than checks the recaptcha and does some operations. I get the error "Undefined index: recaptcha_response_field". I suspect that recaptcha won't work if the validation is done on the same page as the form that sent the variables. Are my suspicions correct and is it better if I move the validation code to another file?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reference - What does this error mean in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12769982/reference-what-does-this-error-mean-in-php)

Comment: Is there any field in your form with this name "recaptcha_response_field" ? I did not see any field with this name in your html form. If this field is not in the form then this error will be for this reason

Comment: @AwladLiton doesn't recaptcha create that field with recaptcha_get_html($publickey) ?

Comment: I think You should have add generated html also. May be there is no input field is submitting with this name?

Comment: First var_dump $_POST, you can see what is in there and if the `recaptcha_response_field` is really there

Comment: Try to inspect your form element and check that what are the fields generated or var_dump post

Comment: @RonaldSwets as I said earlier, recaptcha_response_field is not sent but all the other fields in the form are. I double checked the hierarchy in the html and everything seems correct.

Comment: So recaptcha_response_field  were not in post data. You are missing something in recaptcha library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the 
    form 
tag outside of the 
    table 
tag. I don't know why but it worked.

Comment: Most often when I get this error it is because the captcha isn't in the right spot in the HTML.

Answer (score 3):

It works if you validate on the same page.
You are accessing the variable for checking:

```
if ($_POST["recaptcha_response_field"]) {
```

That most likely causes the error, it should be

```
if (isset($_POST["recaptcha_response_field"])) {
```

Comment: That should eliminate the notice but not the problem, the response field will still be empty and the functions inside the if will never be executed.